# Ideal gas law with two types of gases

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Suppose a container with volume $V$. If I put 2 different types of monoatomic ideal gas, say type $A$ and type $B$, such that there are $N_1$ particles of gas $A$ and $N_2$ particles of gas $B$, with temperature $T$ and pressure $P$, can I still use the ideal gas law? In other words, is the following true?

$$
PV = (N_1 + N_2)k_BT
$$

Comment: I think the $V$ should be removed and the $N_{s}$ should go to $n_{s}$ (i.e., number densities), just to avoid a possible issue with partial pressures/volumes.  I am also inclined to think that each gas gets its own polytrope index... Oh you stated both are monatomic, okay that should be fine...

Answer (score 2):

Yes N is N.  The partial just add up in a linear manner.  Air is as mixture and you use the ideal gas law.